# How to center text in TASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

*Hi guys.
I have a problem here in TASM.
Here I have codes using ASCII code to display a name.
How will I put the output in the center?.*

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.code

start:

Mov ah, 2
Mov dl, 68
Int 21h

Mov ah, 2
Mov dl, 97
Int 21h
Mov ah, 2
Mov dl, 114
Int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
mov al,00h
int 21h

end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GET CURSOR POSITION AND SIZE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0088.htm) and [SET CURSOR POSITION](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0087.htm) interrupts for that:

```
mov ah,3    ; Get the current cursor position
mov bh,0
int 10h

mov ah,2    ; Set cursor position
mov bh,0
mov dl,39   ; New column. In an 80 column text mode this will just about center
            ; the 3 characters 
; We wanto to stay on the same row, so we don't change dh
int 10h
```

Comment: Where will I put these codes?...

Before I input the codes for the letters?...

Or after?...

Thanks =}

Comment: Before you print the letters.

Comment: Sir another question, I can now center align the three letters.

Now, I want to put another letters, below those 3 letters.

How can I do that?

Comment: Make another call to `int 21h / ah=2` with `dl` and `dh` set to the column and row you want.

Comment: At what part of the program sir?